# weblogic resource allocation limit

Tags: java, jpa, concurrency, weblogic

i have a list of 1000 records fetched from oracle db. i want to process this list concurrently. therefore i have used java parallel streams. the problem is it threw error `weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceLimitException: No resources currently available in pool ERDS to allocate to applications, please increase the size of the pool and retry` in some iterations. also seems to be interrupted and not complete the loop. i think if i use stream instead of parallel stream there will be no problem. but i need to do the operation by multiple threads to increase performance and reduce process time (in case i need to process a 10 thousand record list for example ). here is the code:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class TPTimer {

@Inject
private Service service;

@Inject
Logger logger;

@Inject
EntityManager em;


@Schedule(hour = "11", persistent = false)
public void doTask() {
    try {
      
         
            sendSMS();
           
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}


private void sendSMS() {
    try {
        String txt = ".....";
        List<Object[]> list = em.createNativeQuery("some query")
                .setMaxResults(1000)
                .getResultList();

        list.parallelStream().forEach(t -> service.joinWithdebit(txt, t));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
}
```

}

and

```
    @Stateless
    public class Service {


public void joinWithdebit(String txt, Object[] arr) {
        try {
            em.joinTransaction();
            List list = em.createNativeQuery("query")
                    .setParameter(1, String.valueOf(arr[2]))
                    .getResultList();
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                List res = em.createNativeQuery("q")
                        .setParameter(1, String.valueOf(arr[1]))
                        .setParameter(2, String.valueOf(arr[0]))
                        .getResultList();
                if (res.size() > 0)
                    sendSms(txt, arr);
          
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(e);
        }
    }

     @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void sendSms(String txt, Object[] arr) {
        try {
            em.joinTransaction();
            User user = userManager.getUserByName(String.valueOf(arr[0]));
            boolean bool = smsService.isSmsSent(user, txt);
            if (bool) {
                String now = DateUtils.format(new Date(), "yyyyMMdd");
                em.createNativeQuery("insert into sms_table(...) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,SYSDATE)")
                        .setParameter(1, new BigDecimal(arr[0] + "5" + "01"))
                        .setParameter(2, String.valueOf(arr[2]))
                        .setParameter(3, "01")
                        .setParameter(4, String.valueOf(arr[0]))
                        .setParameter(5, now)
                        .setParameter(6, now)
                        .setParameter(7, user != null ? user.getMobile() : "-")
                        .setParameter(8, "5")
                        .executeUpdate();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).info("320220:error while sending sms");
        }
    }
```

}

is it ok to fetch some records(for ex 20 thousands) and then process them concurrently? i don't want to do the business in a pl/sql function for some reasons. i want to manage the whole business in java. what can be done to optimize this code?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear a JDBC pool connection starvation; if you are going to run parallel threads, then you need to handle the pool connections, which are enough for your requirement.

Comment: How should i handle that?